# Symfony2.1 mapping error: class_parents()

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a problem trying to get data from a table (via entity) using Doctrine2 in a Symfony2.1 project. Here is the controller where I get the error:

```
/**
 * Country list
 */
public function countrylistAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $countryList = $em->getRepository('ProjectBaseBundle:SYS_TCountry')
        ->findAll();

    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()),
        array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));

    return new Response($serializer->serialize($countryList, 'json'));
}
```

The entity:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Project\BaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="SYS_TCountry")
 */
class SYS_TCountry
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $idcountry;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=75, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    ....

    public function getIdcountry()              { return $this->idcountry; }
    public function getName()                   { return $this->name; }
    public function getA2()                     { return $this->a2; }
    public function getA3()                     { return $this->a3; }
    public function getIdstatus()               { return $this->idstatus; }
    public function setIdcountry($idcountry)    { $this->idcountry = $idcountry; }
    public function setName($name)              { $this->name = $name; }
    public function setA2($a2)                  { $this->a2 = $a2; }
    public function setA3($a3)                  { $this->a3 = $a3; }
    public function setIdstatus($idstatus)      { $this->idstatus = $idstatus; }

    public function __toString()                { return $this->idcountry; }

}
```

Config.yml:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

And this is the error:

```
Warning: class_parents(): 
Class Company\Project\BaseBundle\Entity\SYS_TCountry does not exist and could not be loaded in 
/var/www/project/src/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php line 40
```

It is strange because, as Doctrine says in console, the mapping is properly done: I test it executing *php app/console doctrine:mapping:info*:

```
[OK]   Company\Project\BaseBundle\Entity\SYS_TCountry
```

and if I execute a query in console everything goes fine -> app/console doctrine:query:sql 'SELECT * FROM SYS_TCountry', that return results.

I do not know if using **Symfony2.1** I have to configure something different to the 2.0 version, but seems the same because the mapping is Doctrine responsibility.

Comment: What is your configuration for `orm` section in `config.yml`? Could you attach it to your question?

Comment: Yes, I have attached it in the message, but is the default settings. In another Symfony2 project with the same config everything works perfectly

Comment: Probably, you have to manually set the mapping in configuration also?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony follows the PSR-0 standard for filenames. That, amongst other things, means that if you use an underscore in your class name, it will replace it with a directory separator when deciding where your class should live, like this:

```
\namespace\package\Class_Name => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package/Class/Name.php
```

So, if you have a class named SYS_TCountry it would expect to find it in

```
Company/Project/BaseBundle/Entity/SYS/TCountry.php
```

instead of

```
Company/Project/BaseBundle/Entity/SYS_TCountry.php
```

I think that your best solution would be to change the filename and class name to SYSTCountry. You don´t need to change the table name.

Comment: Thanks! Work perfectly.
It is strange, SYS_TCountry class works fine in Symfony2.0 project. The 2.1 is more strict on this matter. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class entity name is not compliant with [`PSR-0`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) which causes the loading error.
If you rename your entity to `SYSTCountry` everything will work fine!

**Edit:** Default Symfony2 and Doctrine autoloaders **ARE** `PSR-0` compliant.