# PSR-0 autoloader issue

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-0

I have trouble instantiating class by path in my `PSR-0` autoloaded project. Structure is as follows:

```
| - src/
|    - Models/
|        - My_New_Model_Migration.php
|        - ...
|    SeederCommand.php
| - vendor/
|     - ...
| composer.json
```

And Composer autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "" : [
            "src/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Not to get to much in `SeederCommand` class, it is basically a Doctrine/migrations class which is supposed to create a migration with `up()` and `down()` methods.

Inside the function responsible for generating those I have this part:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/Models/{$model}_Migration.php")) {
    $class = "{$model}_Migration";
    $instantiated = new $class;
    ....
}
```

When echoing I notice that file indeed does exist, so this part is working as it should. When newing up the class however I am getting an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   '/var/www/html/.../src/Models/My_New_Model_Migration.php' not found in
>   /var/www/html/.../src/SeederCommand.php:97

Since paths are correct, I presume the issue must be in way a `PSR-0` autoloader works by parsing paths by underscore?

Is there some way around it?

**EDIT:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696219/why-is-underscore-converted-to-directory-separator-in-the-psr-0-standard) doesn't help me as it explains the 'why' of the autoloader story. I know how both `PSR-0` and `PSR-4` autoloaders work on the high level. I would like a way around the fact that autoloader wants a directory structure where there is none (and I don't want it introduced in this case).

**EDIT2:**

`SeederCommand` class requires autoload file:

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
```

I've tried doing a `dump-autoload` and renaming class to one without underscores and same thing happens, so I might have done something wrong with autoloading itself.

**EDIT3:**

I have tried newing up a class I renamed to a non-underscore version. For example newing up `MyNewClass` works, but `My_New_Class` throws an error.

Comment: I don't need the 'why', I know how autoloader works :) I need way around it if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have underscores in your classname, and not have them in the directory structure.

If your class is named `Models_MyWhatever_Migration`, because you dynamically add the string "MyWhatever" to the classname during migration, that class MUST be placed in `src/Models/MyWhatever/Migration.php`. You cannot have it in `src/Models/MyWhatever_Migration.php`.

If you want to keep the underscore as part of the filename, you have to switch to PSR-4 and use namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

### Error while creating instance of new class

```php
$class = __DIR__ . "/Models/{$model}_Migration.php";
$instantiated = new $class;
```

This is wrong because you cannot create an instance of a class by its file name like:

```
$instance = new /var/www/html/.../Class.php; // <-- wrong
```

Instead you need to use the class name and namespace:

```
$instance = new \Project\Namespace\Class;
```

So in your specific case it could be something like

```
$class = "\\Project\\Models\\".$model."_Migration";
// ^ depends on the real namespace and name of your migration classes
$instantiated = new $class;
```

### PSR-0 and underscores

After reading the [PSR-0 Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) again, I honestly think there is no way to achieve what you want (having a class name with underscore but no directory for it) while using PSR-0. The standard explicitly states:

> Each _ character in the CLASS NAME is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

### Possible solution: Classmap autoloader

But you could use [composer's classmap autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) for those files instead:

> This map is built by scanning for classes in all .php and .inc files in the given directories/files. You can use the classmap generation support to define autoloading for all libraries that do not follow PSR-0/4. To configure this you specify all directories or files to search for classes.

It could maybe look like that (but I was not able to test it):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "" : [
            "src/"
        ]
    },
    "classmap": ["src/Models/"]
}
```

Comment: You're right. This does solve one part of the problem, however `PSR-0` issue still exists (check my last edit)

Comment: @Norgul I just updated my answer, maybe it can help you.